# Getting error while querying to get tables partition metadata in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery project has one dataset and around **1005** tables.I am running query to get partition metadata for tables.

Query is
`SELECT count(*) FROM bq-tf-test-500-298.unravelFr8ks4.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS;`

Following error getting   `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS query attempted to read too many tables. Please add more restrictive filters`
Attaching
[Query screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atVmI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Partitions view is currently at [Preview](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-partitions) state at the moment. It is possible that the tables it can read are limited. As the message suggests, a workaround of adding more filters could run your query.